# Is there an aggresive opening for black if white does not accept the Traxler's counterattack?

Tags: gambits, attack, aggressive-play, fried-liver-attack, traxler-counter-attack

I want to play sharp, complicated Traxler games in bullet. To do this, I *must* play the Two Knights Defence. The problem is that rarely people go for the Fried Liver, and usually I play the Four Knights Italian or the Giuoco Piano opening.

```
[FEN "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/4p3/2B1P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 4 4"]

1. Nc3
```

or

```
[FEN "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/4p3/2B1P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 4 4"]

1. c3
```

or

```
[FEN "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/4p3/2B1P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 4 4"]

1. d3
```

Is there a gambit or an aggressive opening/response that could complicate the game from this position into an attacking aggressive battle for **Black**?

**NOTE:** I don't expect the opening to be any good

Comment: Against 4. d3 there is 4...h6 with the idea of immediate g5 and later on castling long and a kingside storm. No concrete lines as White is way too flexible to give any. Against 4. Nc3 Nxe4 is good for Black in terms of initiative. Both are not overwhelming but their potential should not be underestimated.

Comment: If you are looking for a gambit which is more forcing than the Traxler and suitable for bullet chess -- perhaps the Latvian fits the bill. It is theoretically dubious of course, but it can be played over 90% of the times that White starts with e4.

Answer (score 3):

The Traxler counter-attack starts if White plays Ng5 in this position.

```
[FEN "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/4p3/2B1P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 4 4"]

1. Ng5
```

Without Ng5, there is no Traxler counter-attack.

I think that 1.e4 e5 is not the best way of preparing an attacking and aggressive battle with Black. That is why I play 1.e4 c5 and go for the Sicilian Najdorf variation. I think that asymmetry is a good way of seeking imbalance and dynamic play. While symmetry is more likely to lead to less dynamic positions. Thus, 1.e4 c5 and 1.d4 f5 are approaches to seek more dynamic play, in most extreme cases, by castling on opposite sides and launching pawn storms. Your opening choice leaves White with the option of accepting with Ng5 or declining with a different move. If you want to ensure dynamic play, I think it is better to look for opening systems where you have more control of where the game goes so to speak. I hope this helps.

Comment: I agree, I also like the Najdorf as it consistently offers on offensive game but, the traxler is ... just another story.

Comment: @Harton if you want to get sharp play, go for castling on opposite sides. Wait until the opponent castles Kingside and then castle Queenside and launch a pawn storm on the Kingside. It might not be the best way objectively, but it will definitely become a dynamic position.

Answer (score 3):

In response to:

- 4.c3. This outright loses a pawn to 4...Nxe4. I have a hard time believing White will play this often.
- 4.Nc3. This move is tame, effectively accepting a symmetrical position with minimal advantage if Black plays 4...Bc5. Black does not have to acquiesce and could play 4...Nxe4 5. Nxe4 d5 giving Black easy development and a comfortable game. I get that it's not what exactly you are looking for, but with open lines in the center you should be able to find tactical lines.
- That leaves 4.d3, against which you can play 4...d5. This move forces open the center before either side has completed development, making it inherently provocative, but it again allows tactical ideas to surface.

You could also try a different opening in the Sicilian as suggested by Rauan Sagit, but the Two Knights is plenty provocative itself.

Comment: These aggressive d5 lines look interesting. Tactical play, aggresive sacrifises is all I need to be entertained